# Which iPhone app ad solution gives the best rates?

Tags: iphone, ads

I have a free iPhone app downloaded by 3,000 users, most of whom use my app at least once per day.  So I plan to show ads in my app.  Which ad solution is best?  I looked in some sites, but no one is giving clear details about CPMs.

How much will I get for 1,000 impressions using different ad solutions?

Comment: This isn't really programming related

Comment: Not quite sure what 'direct qns' is and your sentence does not seem to make sense.

Comment: Cogsy: How is it not programming related? It's directly related to programming of an application

Comment: "How much money will I get from different ad providers" is not programming related at all. Same as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584313/how-to-determine-how-much-to-charge-for-site-ads

Comment: "How do I integrate ads?" is programming. "Which ad network pays most?" is business. All programming is software, not all software is programming.

Comment: I think "direct qns" means "specific question."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many iPhone ad networks. Perhaps the most popular is AdMob.

I've been using it for my application, iLaugh, for several months now and it's generating decent revenue (average $2000 per month on 175,000 daily ad requests). That low number is partly due to the fact that AdMob displays less than half of my ad requests as CPC ads, instead printing the rest with their sucky Download Exchange program.

What I would recommend, though, is going with AdWhirl, which is a solution that lets you dynamically change ad networks on-the-fly, put your custom ads or automatically balance between ad network to generate the most revenue.

If your app gains traction, you'll probably be better off negotiating a deal with one of the exclusive ad networks that veto your app based on traffic and merit and only accept the big guys. I've been accepted by the JumpTap network (implemented by Pinch Media) and am planning to use their ads as well as AdMob's in the next iteration of my app, which uses AdWhirl.

Oh, and I run a mailing list specifically dedicated to these kinds of questions / discussions: [iphonesb](http://groups.google.com/group/iphonesb).

Answer (score 2):

Your mileage will vary. AdMob eCPM between $0.35 and $2.00.

An alternative to choosing a single ad vendor is to use the AdWhirl solution. This lets you dynamically configure ad networks on the fly, even after you have shipped your app.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try out [Moduad](http://www.moduad.com)? It provides virtual goods hosting as well as pay-per-install, pay-per-click advertising.

Answer (score 0):

The major ad networks are so generic that you're only going to see a couple dollar CPM (cost per thousand impressions), if that.

If your ad is specific to a certain market, you'd be better off getting sponsored by an advertiser or two in that market.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a network called MobFox for all my european and american iPhone Traffic. Earning me about $2-$5 eCPM, which is quite amazing.

Still falling back to AdMob (and MobClix in some apps) for all the other traffic which MF cannot fill.